# Site Columns & Content Types Missing during VS Development

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column

Just getting into SharePoint development however we're encountering an issue following nearly every tutorial!

Site Columns & Content Types do not seem to appear in SharePoint after Deploying an app via VS 2013!

We're currently following [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/Developing-SharePoint-2013-Core-Solutions/02) Channel9 tutorial. Fairly straightforward - they create an app, add a Column & Content Type and at 37 minutes in they deploy their app to SharePoint. After doing so they navigate to Site Settings -> Site Columns and can see the column created in the project. 
We however don't see this! The 'site column' and 'content type' aren't listed in SharePoint 2013.

This occurs with every tutorial we've followed, the content type and column simply isn't there. Any ideas where we're going wrong? Are we missing a step?

**Note**: Only difference from what we're doing to the Channel9 tutorial is we create an "App for SharePoint 2013" whereas they're using a "SharePoint 2013 Empty Project" template.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you working with SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2013? If it is SharePoint Online, did you create a SharePoint-hosted app?

Comment: @RodrigoMolinas we're using SharePoint Online with Office 365. And no we're using a provider hosted app just as the tutorials we're following do.

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding your site columns and content types to the app project, these will get deployed to the App Web, not the Host Web (site you are cheking for the content type). For more information around the subject check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179925.aspx).

If you want to deploy content types to the host web, you will need to use the Remote Provisioning Patter. Check provisioning patterns [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2013/08/23/site-provisioning-techniques-and-remote-provisioning-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

-Hope it helps